# Get db value from within controller in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a value from the database inside a controller like this:

```
//Load model
$this->load->model('files/files_model');        

//Lookup file
$file = $this->files_model->findfilebyid('1');

echo "Filepath: " . $file->filepath . "<br>";
echo "Filename: " . $file->filename . "<br>";
```

But when I do this, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error. I Also tried $file->['filepath'] and $file[0]->filepath, but this does not work.

Printing the array with 'print_r(array_values($file))' gives this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fileid] => 1 [filenamefriendly] => Kiosk manual [filename] => kiosks [filenamepath] => filestorage [fileownerid] => 4 [filepermissiontype] => global [filepermissioncompanyid] => 0 [filecategoryid] => 1 [filecreatedate] => 2015-11-20 00:00:00 [filedescription] => This is the manual of the kiosks [filetype] => pdf ) )
```

Am I trying to put an array in an array or something? How can I access the values?

Comment: `$file[0]->filepath` Does not work?

Comment: Try casting the `$file` variable ie `$file = (array) $file; var_dump($file)`

Comment: First thing to check is that `findfildbyid()` is returning something. The error indicates that `$file` is either NULL or FALSE and not the Object you are expecting. Show us your model code.

Comment: Hmm; $file[0]->filenamepath work. I should learn to use the right database column names :)

However, I'm curious why I need to add [0].. is that because I put an array in an array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're returning a full result set (which is an array of objects)
While what you actually wants is a single object since the 'id' should be a primary key.

In your `findfilebyid` it should be something like:

```
public function findfilebyid ($id) {
       $q = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('files');
       return $q->row();
}
```